# Why am I receiving a 404 when using proxy_pass with NginX?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use `Nginx` to expose my Web APIs on port 80 using `proxy_pass`. The Web APIs are written in Node using `Express` and they are all running on separate port numbers.

I have locations working in the `nginx.conf` file when pulling static files from the root and /test, but receive a `404 error` when trying to redirect to the API.  The API I'm testing with runs on `port 8080` and I'm able to access and test it using Postman.

This is using `Nginx 1.16.1` being hosted on a `Windows 2016 Server`

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost crowdtrades.com;
//Root and /test locations are working correctly
        location / {
            root   c:/CrowdTrades;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /test/ {
            root   c:/CrowdTrades/test;
            index  test.html;
        }
//     #Test2 this is the location I'm not able to get working
    location /test2/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api/signup/;
    }

        }


    }
```

Comment: Does error log has something useful information when send request to /test2?

Comment: Try this command `sudo tcpdump -i <interface> -A 'port 8080'` and request again, does it output something?

Answer (score 0):

So after trying all kinds of configuration changes and restarting Nginx each time I gave up for the night. My cloud VM is scheduled to shut down at night, when I picked this up in the AM it was working. I have no idea why it's working now but restarting the server seemed to help.